# Parse XML to JSON and back ... with xml2js and xmlbuilder?

Tags: node.js, xml-parsing, xml-builder

Trying to parse XML into JSON with [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) and then return the JSON to XML using [xmlbuilder](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/) (usually after modifying the content programmatically).

I *think* that the two should be complements, per this post https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/issues/69.  But am having some difficulty, and it's gotta be that I'm not getting the config parameters right.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
var xml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../xml/theme.xml', 'utf8');

xml2js.parseString(xml, { attrkey: '@',  xmlns: true }, function(err, json) {
    var xml2 = xmlbuilder.create(json,
       {version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: true}
    ).end({pretty: true, standalone: true})
});
```

Here's the first bit of the original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a:theme xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" name="Office Theme">
    <a:themeElements>
        <a:clrScheme name="Office">
            <a:dk1>
                <a:sysClr val="windowText" lastClr="000000"/>
            </a:dk1>
            <a:lt1>
                <a:sysClr val="window" lastClr="FFFFFF"/>
            </a:lt1>
            <a:dk2>
                <a:srgbClr val="1F497D"/>
            </a:dk2>
            ...
     </a:themeElements>           
 </a:theme>
```

Here;s how xml2js parses that to JSON, this looks right to me:

```
{
    "a:theme": {
        "@": {
            "xmlns:a": {
                "name": "xmlns:a",
                "value": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main",
                "prefix": "xmlns",
                "local": "a",
                "uri": "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
            },
            "name": {
                "name": "name",
                "value": "Office Theme",
                "prefix": "",
                "local": "name",
                "uri": ""
            }
        },
        "@ns": {
            "uri": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main",
            "local": "theme"
        },
        "a:themeElements": [
            {
                "@ns": {
                    "uri": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main",
                    "local": "themeElements"
                },
                "a:clrScheme": [
                    {
                        "@": {
                            "name": {
                                "name": "name",
                                "value": "Office",
                                "prefix": "",
                                "local": "name",
                                "uri": ""
                            }
                        },
                        "@ns": {
                            "uri": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main",
                            "local": "clrScheme"
                        },
                       ...
```

Note that in the JSON above:

1. the attribute (e.g. `name=`) are turned into keys inside an `@` object and
2. the attribute values are turned into objects

Now here's how it looks when xmlbuilder turns it back into XML:

```
<a:theme ="[object Object]" ns="[object Object]">
  <a:themeElements ns="[object Object]">
    <a:clrScheme ="[object Object]" ns="[object Object]">
      <a:dk1 ns="[object Object]">
        <a:sysClr ="[object Object]" ns="[object Object]"/>
      </a:dk1>
      <a:lt1 ns="[object Object]">
        <a:sysClr ="[object Object]" ns="[object Object]"/>
      </a:lt1>
       ...
    </a:themeElements>
 </a:theme>
```

So there are two problems that XML builder is facing:
  * it's not recognizing the attribute names within the `@` object and
  * it's not recognizing the attribute value within the attribute object

Hacking it appears that xmlbuilder wants attributes names structured like:

```
  `{ "@name": "Office Theme"} `
```

rather than

```
  `{ "@" : { "name" : { value: "Office Theme" }}}`
```

Should I configure xml2js differently, xmlbuilder differently, or is there a different pair of libraries that can parse XML -> JSON -> XML?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this detour to JSON and back? Modifying the XML directly seems the more sensible approach when XML is what you want to have in the end...

Comment: Great question.  In this case, the UI and DB work with JS/JSON objects, so the ability to represent XML content (e.g. an MS Office doc) as JSON allows user configurations to be applied by mixing in objects without explicitly traversing DOM.  I was hoping the back end would be as simple as `xml2js.parseString(xml, function(err, json) { _.mixin(json, edits); xmlbuilder.create(json).end(); `

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [xml2js package](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) comes with its own XML builder, to which the documentation has to say:

> Since 0.4.0, objects can be also be used to build XML:
>
> ```
> var fs = require('fs'),
>     xml2js = require('xml2js');
>
> var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: 23};
> var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
> var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
> ```
>
> At the moment, a one to one bi-directional
>   conversion is guaranteed only for default configuration, except for
>   attrkey, charkey and explicitArray options you can redefine to your
>   taste.

So, after dropping your custom parser configuration, this works perfectly for me:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

xmlFileToJs('theme.xml', function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw (err);
    jsToXmlFile('theme2.xml', obj, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    })
});
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

function xmlFileToJs(filename, cb) {
    var filepath = path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, filename));
    fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function (err, xmlStr) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        xml2js.parseString(xmlStr, {}, cb);
    });    
}

function jsToXmlFile(filename, obj, cb) {
    var filepath = path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, filename));
    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
    var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
    fs.writeFile(filepath, xml, cb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Task blindness, somehow with the name `xml2js` I missed it's also `js2xml`.

Comment: I noticed that XML comments are dropped when converting from XML to JSON, but I suppose your input XML does not contain mission-critical comments. Be sure to write your file as UTF-8 (it's the default with `fs.writeFile()`, but make it explicit in your code anyway, if only to have it symmetric with `fs.readFile()`). See modified code.

Comment: What is here "cb" and "obj" as an argument in the function?

Comment: @User123 `obj` is the JS object (in `xml2js` format) you want to write to the XML file, and `cb` is the callback function you want to have called when the conversion process is done.

Answer (score 2):

While Converting XML to JSON , The xml2js maps the attributes to '$'. In case if your attributes key Name does not match with the Child Key Name . You could Merge the Attributes with Child elements . HEnce your JSON looks clean.

**

> xml2js.Parser({ignoreAttrs : false, mergeAttrs : true})

**

Might Solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I used it with parseString() of xml2js.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar requirement recently. Had to convert Yahoo weather service xml data into json object. Solved the issue with xml2js and js2xmlparser modules. Thought to share how I did here. An example which I worked out:

```
const https = require('https');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

https.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22surat%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2F    datatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation);

        parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

After this one can use [js2xmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js2xmlparser) for converting the obtained json to xml.

```
js2xmlparser.parse("weather", data); 
....
```

here's a Github link for the detailed code: https://github.com/joshiparthin/ReNode/tree/master/soap-api